# ndk-build .so incompatible target (prebuilt shared library)

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := slabhidtouart
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libslabhidtouart.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := TestJNI
### Add all source file names to be included in lib separated by a whitespace
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := TestJNI.cpp 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := slabhidtouart
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jni
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

compiling with ndk build giving error

```
testjni1//obj/local/armebai/libslabhidtouart.so: incompatible target
```

can anyone tell me where i am going wrong

Edit: `using readelf -d i got this`

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x1fd90 contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libusb-1.0.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libslabhidtouart.so.1]
```

some libraries are marked as needed what that means.

actually i am new to this kind of projects so i was confused with what i need and what i have to do next. now i got some things like i was using a library which is built for another cpu(x86_64) and i need library for ARM, thanks to you guys, you make me clear

Comment: How was libslabhidtouart.so built?

Comment: this file is from silicon lab

Comment: As @Michael suggested, the libslabhidtouart.so might have been build for a different target architecture, and is therefore incompatible to the architecture you're trying to build your lib for. 
Which ABI did you specify in Application.mk?

Comment: Use `readelf -h` or some other tool to find out what target the .so file was built for.

Comment: I got this- ELF Header:
 Magic: 7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Class: ELF32
Data: 2's complement, little endian
Version: 1 (current)
OS/ABI: UNIX - System V
ABI Version: 0
Type: DYN (Shared object file)
Machine:Intel 80386
Version: 0x1
Entry point address: 0xa730
Start of program headers:  52 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:313632 (bytes into file)
Flags: 0x0
Size of this header: 52 (bytes)
Size of program headers: 32 (bytes)
Number of program headers:7
Size of section headers: 40 (bytes)
Number of section headers:  39
Section header string table index: 36

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This reference:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := slabhidtouart
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libslabhidtouart.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

means that you want to use `libslabhidtouart.so` when compiling your module. But .so files are binaries that are compatible only with one specific cpu-architecture/OS.

The error you're getting means that ndk-build is trying to use your .so file while compiling your module for an incompatible target.

Android supports several cpu architectures (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, mips, mips64). You can choose which one you want to support using the *APP_ABI* variable from *Application.mk*. If you set it to `all`, ndk-build will try to use this .so file you're referencing for each of these architectures, but this cannot work.

Your .so file must have been compiled for Android platforms, and you need to have a different version of it for each architecture you're supporting. You can give a dynamic reference to the right .so file, such as `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libslabhidtouart.so` so it looks for your .so file under armeabi-v7a folder when compiling for armeabi-v7a, under x86 for x86, etc.

Of course you need to provide these .so files. If you can't get .so files for all the supported architectures, you'll have to restrict your `APP_ABI` to the architectures of the .so file you have. You can determine the architecture your .so file has been compiled for using readelf.

edit: your latest comment precise that your .so file has been compiled for x86, but I also suspect it's for standard Linux, not Android. You can use readelf -d to check your lib dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Reference link - https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html

Answer (score 0):

prebuilt libraries should be built with corresponding NDK standlone toolchain, somethings like "arm-linux-androideabi-4.9","x86-4.9"...

you can find them in the folder /toochains/

Comment: how will i know which toolchain is needed, and how to select a particular toolchain

Comment: x86] Compile++      : TestJNI <= TestJNI.cpp
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libTestJNI.so
c:/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-lin
x-android/4.8/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: error: C:/Users/ehydro
et/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestJNI1//obj/local/x86/libslabhidtouart.so: inco
patible target

Comment: this is the error i got while my aplication.mk is APP_PLATFORM := android-15
APP_ABI := x86
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions  
APP_STL := stlport_static                     I dont know about ap_abi so i am trying all optiions

Answer (score -2):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := slabhidtouart
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libslabhidtouart.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

compiling with ndk build giving error:

> testjni1//obj/local/armebai/libslabhidtouart.so: incompatible target

```
chmod a+x solve it
```